# Declarations vs definitions

Tags: c#, .net

In C# how does a declaration differ from a definition, i.e.:

1. A class declaration vs a class definition
2. A variable declaration vs definition
3. A method parameter declaration vs definition

In C++, this was rather obvious, but in C# from what I can tell from the ECMA standard and MSDN is that everything is a declaration and where the word definition is used, it is used to mean the same thing as declaration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. That distinction does not exist.  You are referring to the scope of a declaration, the point of definition is irrelevant to the scope of the variable/field.
2. ```
   int x;  // 'x' is declared
   x = 10; // 'x' is assigned


   int y = 20; // 'y' is both declared and assigned
   ```
3. That doesn't make a lot of sense.  A method argument is declared in the method signature.

I think you are a bit confused regarding terminology in 1 and 3.

Comment: Well, in C++: int x=10; // Is not a declaration and is strictly a definition. This is why I am confused with C# terminology. Also, C++ allows class declarations which are completely different from class definitions. C# allows partial classes and completely defined classes, but both appear to be declarations!

Comment: @michael: No, both are definitions.

Comment: @michael: partial classes are just one class split into multiple source files. Some members are defined in one file and some in others.

Comment: @michael, I can't understand what is declaration and what is definition? I think in c++ int x = 10; is definition and declaration. would you explain it?

Comment: @Henk, no, they are declarations, see Section 10.1 (for a complete class) and sections (10.2.4 and 10.2.7) of the C# 4.0 Standard document for partial classes.

Comment: @Michael: You're probably right, I was using the C++ naming. The correction: They are both _like_ C++ definitions.

Comment: Let me suggest that it is silly to read the C++ spec in order to try and understand C# semantics.  Just read the C# spec! =)

Comment: After `int x;` , `x` is very well defined. It just isn't assigned.

Answer (score 23):

> where the word definition is used, it is used to mean the same thing as declaration

Correct.

The concept of a 'declaration' as a soft/forward definition is needed in C and C++ because of their compilation model.  C++ (conceptually) uses single pass compilation, C# is multi-pass. Consider:

```
class Bar; // declaration: needed in C++, illegal and unnecessary in C#

class Foo  // start of definition, counts as a declaration of Foo
{
    Foo f; // use of declared but still incompletely defined class Foo
    Bar b; // use of declared but still undefined class Bar
}

class Bar  //  definition and re-declaration  
{
}
```

C++ can't handle the `Bar b` field without a declaration first. C# can.

Comment: On a related note how does one separate declaration and definition over assemblies? Can declaration be in one assembly and definition in another?

Answer (score 11):

The C++ build model dates from an era where ferrite cores were a dollar a dozen.  Multiple source code files compiled one at a time.  With a single-pass compiler.  A linker to glue everything together.  That made separate declarations in header files and prototypes necessary.

The C# compiler takes ready advantage of modern machine resources.  All source code files that constitute an assembly are compiled at the same time, the compiler makes at least two passes so it can parse declarations before method bodies.  There's still a possible link model but it gets very rarely used.

The only notions of a declaration having to match a definition that I can think of is a delegate type having to match a target method and an interface member declaration having to match its concrete implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Answers to original questions 1, 2, 3: no difference in C#

However might be worth mentioning those terms in regards to methods:

- **Declaration** is place in *Interface* where we just "declare" the signature of the method
- **Definition** is the actual place where we "define" the actual implementation of the declared previously method. (same as "*implementation*")

Comment: I tend to agree, although, I'm not sure the C# community would really care to draw even that distinction.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't because C# doesn't have to make a distinction.

Answer (score 1):

According to Kernighan & Ritchie in "The C Programming Language":
A "declaration" announces the properties of variables; it consists of a name and a list of variables, such as:
int fahr, celsius;

According to Stroustrup in "The C++ Programming Language":
A "declaration" is a statement that introduces a name into the program. It specifies a type for that name. A type defines the proper use of a name or an expression.

Neither book specifically defines "definition". But both use the term in the scientific sense of the VALUE of a variable. Thus a function declaration declares the function's calling signature. A function definition contains the actual code.

The need for having separate meanings in these languages is because of yesteryear's compilers. They needed to know the types of names ahead of time, before the name was actually used. Otherwise they would need to make another pass through the source code.