# C++ Undeclared Identifier on Object creation

Tags: c++, object

So I am new to c++, coming from C#. This is giving me several errors when compiling, which all seem to relate to this object declaration. Anyone able to show me the right way to do this?

I get an undeclared identifier where i declare tri(sideLength).

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337294/creating-an-object-with-or-without-new) as a reference for object declaration, but it doesn't seem to be helping me.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>    // Provides cout
#include <iomanip>     // Provides setw function for setting output width
#include <cstdlib>     // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <cassert>     // Provides assert function
#include <stdexcept>
#include <math.h> 

using namespace std;   // Allows all standard library items to be used

void setup_cout_fractions(int fraction_digits)
// Precondition: fraction_digits is not negative.
// Postcondition: All double or float numbers printed to cout will now be
// rounded to the specified digits on the right of the decimal.
{
    assert(fraction_digits > 0);
    cout.precision(fraction_digits);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
    if (fraction_digits == 0)
        cout.unsetf(ios::showpoint);
    else
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
}

int main()
{
    const int MAX_SIDE_LENGTH = 6;
    const int INITIAL_LENGTH = 1;
    const int DIGITS = 4;
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 6;

    // Set up the output for fractions and print the table headings.
    setup_cout_fractions(DIGITS);

    // Each iteration of the loop prints one line of the table.
    for (int sideLength = 0; sideLength < MAX_SIDE_LENGTH; sideLength += 1)
    {
        EquilateralTriangle tri(sideLength);
        //Square sq(sideLength);
        //Pentagon_Reg pent(sideLength);
        //Hexagon_Reg hex(sideLength);
        //Heptagon_Reg hept(sideLength);
        //Octagon_Reg octa(sideLength);

        cout << "Type: " << tri.Name() << "has area: " << tri.Area() << " with SideLength = " << sideLength;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//Template

class GeometricFigure
{
public:
    GeometricFigure() { }
    double SideLength;
    virtual double Area() { return 0; };
    virtual char* Name() { return ""; };
};

class EquilateralTriangle : public GeometricFigure {
public:
    EquilateralTriangle(double sideLength)
    {
        SideLength = sideLength;
    }
    char* Name() { return "Equilateral Triangle"; }
    double Area() { return (sqrt(3) / 2 * pow(SideLength, 2)); }
};
```

Comment: What is the error. Did you try moving your classes up above the main function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, the compiler reads your code from top-to-bottom, *once*. This is a holdover from when early C compilers only had a few kilobytes of memory to work with - C was designed so that a compiler would only need to look at a little bit of the code at a time.

Because of this, things must have been declared or defined as necessary, before you try to use them.

Move both classes somewhere before `main`. `GeometricFigure` must be before `EquilateralTriangle`, and `EquilateralTriangle` must be before `main`.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting backstory to that too.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to "declare" or tell the compiler, where to look for the EquilateralTriangle and GeometricFigure, "before" you use it first. you might want to take a look at the similar discussion at - [C# declarations vs definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064668/c-sharp-declarations-vs-definitions)